# Prove: $dim(W_1 \bigcap W_2) \le n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a vector space V having dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively, where $m \ge n $

Prove that $dim(W_1 \bigcap W_2) \le n$

My attempt:

Clearly, $W_1 \bigcap W_2 \subset W_2$ and clearly $W_1 \bigcap W_2$ is a subspace.

note that $W_2$ is a vector space, and note that $W_1 \bigcap W_2$ is a subspace of $W_2$

thus,  $dim(W_1 \bigcap W_2) \le dim(W_2) = n$

Comment: Looks good to me – provided you are allowed to use (or know how to prove) that if $A$ is a subspace of $B$ then the dimension of $A$ is at most equal to the dimension of $B$.

Comment: Yes, we are allowed to use any theorems in the textbook for use in practice/hwk/exam problems. And I did memorize the proof in question. Thank you for your time.